# The graphics is drawing on top of the UI, in java swing,

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint

When I’m drawing on a Jpanel within the ***paint()*** method (by inheriting JPanel)
the graphics appear on top of my buttons and other UI components,
In the components aren’t visible,
So how can I draw the **components** on top of the **graphics**?

Comment: Please show code or it didn't happen. Also, you should not override a JPanel's paint method, but rather its paintComponent method, and you should make sure to call the super method within the override.

Comment: I’m extending JPanel end Override the paint method to draw pictures on background,
Then I’m using it for a panel to add buttons

Comment: **Again**, to draw images on the background, ou should not override a JPanel's paint method, but rather its paintComponent method. What about this is not clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

> The Paint Methods
> The rules that apply to AWT's lightweight components
>   also apply to Swing components -- for instance, `paint()` gets called
>   when it's time to render -- except that Swing further factors the
>   `paint()` call into three separate methods, which are invoked in the
>   following order:
>   
> `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
>
>      protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) 
>
>      protected void paintChildren(Graphics g)`
>
> Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`. Although the API allows it, there is generally no
>   reason to override `paintBorder()` or `paintComponents()` (and if you do,
>   make sure you know what you're doing!). This factoring makes it easier
>   for programs to override only the portion of the painting which they
>   need to extend. For example, this solves the AWT problem mentioned
>   previously where a failure to invoke `super.paint()` prevented any
>   lightweight children from appearing.